# How to programatically upload/post an image to an image hosting website without a browser?

Tags: c#, .net, upload

I want to write a simple utility to upload images to various free image hosting websites like TinyPic or Imageshack via a right-click context menu for the file.

How can I do this using .NET?  I've seen some linux scripts that use cURL to post images to these website but I'm not sure how I could create the post request, complete with an image in C#?

Can someone point me in the right direction?

---

EDIT:

I've found a pretty good resource.  Cropper, a free screenshot tool written in .net, has a lot of open-source plugins.  One of them is a SendToTinyPic.. complete with source.  Link here:
http://www.codeplex.com/cropperplugins

Answer (score 4):

The [FlickrNet API](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=FlickrNet) makes this extremely easy for working with Flickr from .NET.  You have to have a Flickr account as well as an [API key and shared secret](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.api_keys.htm).  Once you have what you need, working with the API is very simple:

```
// http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.api_keys.html
string flickrApiKey = "<api key>";
string flickrApiSharedSecret = "<shared secret>";
string flickrAuthenticationToken = "<authentication token>";

Flickr flickr = new Flickr( flickrApiKey, flickrApiSharedSecret );

flickr.AuthToken = flickrAuthenticationToken;    

foreach ( FileInfo image in new FileInfo[] { 
    new FileInfo( @"C:\image1.jpg" ), 
    new FileInfo( @"C:\image2.jpg" ) } )
{
    string photoId = flickr.UploadPicture(
        image.FullName, image.Name, image.Name, "tag1, tag2" );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use HttpWebRequest.

Using this class, you can POST data to a remote HTTP address, just set the mime/type to multi-part/form encoded, and post the binary data from the image with the request.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

For ImageShack, take a look to [this Application](http://www.anappaday.com/downloads/2006/10/day-19-jedi-image-shacker.html).

Answer (score 0):

[TinyPic.com](http://tinypic.com) doesn't have an API as far as I know, but the Cropper SendToTinyPic Plugin tries to upload using "Screen scraping". The official version of the plugin doesn't work right now, but I put together a patch using the same approach, and submitted it to the [cropperplugins project](http://cropperplugins.codeplex.com). It's just one source module that changed. Anyone can download the plugins project, and then drop in my patch and it should work.

With the patch, it's PritScrn or Alt-PrntScrn will save the image and upload to tinypic, and stuff the URL of the raw image on your clipboard.  All in 2 seconds. easy.

If you don't want the actual tool, you can still look at the source code of my patch to see how to POST a page with form-data and a file upload.  No direct link.  See http://cropperplugins.codeplex.com/SourceControl/PatchList.aspx and look for #3239.

---

This example image was produced and then auto-uploaded to tinypic.com with the Alt-PrtScrn key-combo. 
[image: Example image]

To embed it here, I just had to ctrl-V because the URL is stored on the clipboard.

Comment: This no longer works.  TinyPic has changed their transaction flow to include a captcha in front of every upload. Also they've obfuscated a few things as well.  and I've come to learn that the terms of service on TinyPic prohibit using a script or app to upload images. So... This is no longer a good example.  On the other hand CropperPlugins has other plugins that do similar work - for Imgur, ImageShack, TwitPic and Flickr.  Check it out. open source.